# Divide an array by the sum of all values - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array and I want to divide the array the the sum of all values.

```
array([0.6469012 ,  0.50709077, 0.12970407})

sum 1.28369604

New array ([0.50393643, 0.222048277,    0.0394994140])
```

I tried this code but it didn't work :(

```
ind_weight2=ind_weight/ind_weight.sum[:,None]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.sum()` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *divide an array*? Divide each element of the array by the sum of all elements?

Comment: `old = array([0.6469012 ,  0.50709077, 0.12970407]); new = x/x.sum()`?

Comment: If your goal is to divide each element of the original array by the sum of the original, your new array is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your array `my_array`, use `numpy.sum`:

```
my_array_normalized = my_array / numpy.sum(my_array)
```

Comment: Equivalently, one can use the member function `my_array.sum()`

Comment: @BenJones Indeed numpy offers some syntax shortcuts =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'divide the array the sum of all values'. However if your goal is to create an array in which the values are divided by the sum of the original array values, then you could just do this using list comprehensions.

```
a = [0.6469012, 0.50709077, 0.12970407]
sum = sum(a)           # Calculate sum
b = [e/sum for e in a] # Create new array, where each element is divided by the sum
print(a)
print(sum)
print(b)
```

Result:

```
[0.6469012, 0.50709077, 0.12970407]
1.28369604
[0.503936430309468, 0.3950240198606518, 0.1010395498298803]
```

As you see this does not return the array of numbers that you provided in the question so I'm not sure, if this is really what you want

Comment: Your answer generalises straightforwardly to Python `lists` though the `numpy` solutions do take advantage of vectorization and homogeneous data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
    new_array=array/sum(array)